# web application multiple calls to executable

Tags: multithreading, web-applications, executable

Sorry, but I am a complete noob to web applications, and I was just wondering what happens if my web application makes a call to an external binary executable which can take some time to process an input file, and multiple users try to call it at the same time, or when one user tries to call it while it is still running the previous process?

I think this has something to do with threading, but I'm not sure how that applies to external executables.....if someone could provide a resource for me to learn about how it works that would be great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process is launched it has it's isolated from other processes, and the same process can be launched several times, the only limitation being CPU and memory utilization. You have to use some concurrent access protection if writing to shared file, but if you do database access the DB engine takes care of concurrent access so it's not a problem.